# filter based on SELECT and input value

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Ok, I'm missing something.  Basically I have a grid.  Above it is a search/filter bar (I allow searching across all the data, But I'm trying to also get them target the search input to a specific column in the dataset.

```
<label>Search: </label>
<input id='searchTerm' ng-model='searchTerm'/>
<label>Filter: </label>
<select id='filterKey'ng-model="filterList">
<option value='$'>ALL</option>
<option ng-repeat='dKey in dataKeys' value='{{dKey}}'>{{dKey}}</option>
</select>
```

All the data does populate for the dropdown filter and the grid..  So,

`LastName, FirstName, Age, Roles, Status
Last1     First1     23   Mgt    Retired
Last2     First2     24   Mgt    Retired
Last3     First3     24   Mgt    Retired
Last3     First4     22   Mgt    Retired
Last5     First5     25   Mgt    Retired`

Some if the select box is set to ALL then it just displays al lthe rows with a match to what was typed in the Search input (a search of "Last3" would return:

`LastName, FirstName, Age, Roles, Status
Last3     First3     24   Mgt    Retired
Last3     First4     22   Mgt    Retired`

But if the "age" was selected from the fitler dropdown and 24 was entered in the search input, you'd get:

`LastName, FirstName, Age, Roles, Status
Last2     First2     24   Mgt    Retired
Last3     First3     24   Mgt    Retired`

And if "Last2" was typed in the search input the but filter was set yo "age", you'd get:

`LastName, FirstName, Age, Roles, Status`

I'm sure it's simple btu I'm stuggling.  And I'm sure I'm leaving some piece of code out in the above, but let me know and I'll correct it.  The grid does populate and the search input does work - I just can't figure out how to force the search input to look ONLY at a specific column.
   For example, if I'm looking for everyone that is 24 and it will currently find any data with "24" in it --- like a phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search on the property `lastName` of your objects, the filter must be

```
{
  lastName: 'foo'
}
```

So, create a function in your controller that returns an object with the selected key, and the entered value, and use the result of this function as a filter:

```
$scope.getFilter = function() {
    var result = {};
    result[$scope.filterList] = $scope.searchTerm;
    return result;
}
```

and in the view:

```
ng-repeat="list | filter:getFilter()"
```

You should really rename `filterList` to something more meaningful, like `filterKey`.

Comment: Thank you.  And yes, will be using filterKey.  Let me give what you wrote a try momentarily.    Will write back shortly (cuz this is drivign me nuts. lol)

Comment: Thank you JB ... you are a life saver.  Very much appreciated and it's very logical.  It was just driving me nuts cuz I knew it was something easy.  Many thanks.

Comment: @CS you're welcome. You're new here, so I'll explain: the way to thank someone who answered your question, and to mark the question as answered for other people, is to "accept" the answer, by clicking on the grey tick at the left. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yeah, first time posting here tho.  Rep doesn't seem to be high enough - but I did click on it. eheheh - had to wait a little longer.  Wasnt' a rep thing.  Markde now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can use. I accumulated the column name in the select box. And wrote a custom filter to search by that particular filter when a value is selected. If 'ALL' is selected then it is searching all the columns. Hope it helps.

```js
var app = angular.module('appX', []);

app.controller('ctrlX', function($scope) {
  $scope.dataSet = [{
    firstname: 'first 1',
    lastname: 'last 1',
    age: '24',
    sex: 'F'
  }, {
    firstname: 'first 2',
    lastname: 'last 2',
    age: '21',
    sex: 'M'
  }, {
    firstname: 'first 3',
    lastname: 'last 3',
    age: '24',
    sex: 'M'
  }, {
    firstname: 'first 4',
    lastname: 'last 4',
    age: '26',
    sex: 'F'
  }];

  $scope.keyList = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.dataSet, function(val, key) {
    angular.forEach(val, function(v, k) {
      if ($scope.keyList.indexOf(k) < 0) {
        $scope.keyList.push(k);
      }
    })
  })
})

app.filter('mycustomSearch', function() {
  return function(input, option) {
    if (!option.type || !option.term) {
      return input;
    }
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(val, key) {
      if (val[option.type].indexOf(option.term) > -1) {
        result.push(val);
      }
    })
    return result;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appX">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlX">
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input id='searchTerm' ng-model='searchTerm' />
    <label>Filter:</label>
    <select id='filterKey' ng-model="filterList" ng-options="x for x in keyList">
      <option value=''>ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="x in keyList">{{x}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in dataSet | mycustomSearch:{term:searchTerm, type:filterList} | filter: searchTerm">
            <td>{{x.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{x.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{x.age}}</td>
            <td>{{x.sex}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```